# Preserve anchor style if it doesn't have href attribute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, anchor

I have an anchor element that I use with a button role, so I am not using href attribute on it.

```
<a (click)="doSomething()" role="button">Some data></a>
```

By default in Bootstrap, if no href is set on an anchor element it loses its style (default blue color, underline, hover...).

How can I preserve the Bootstrap style for an anchor that does not have href attribute?

Comment: And using `href="javascript:;"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:   `<a href="javascript:void(0);></a>`